# onPaste converts the pasted file type to image

Tags: java, reactjs, typescript, web-deployment, onpaste

I am looking into solution when users can copy paste any file in order to upload it.

I am using onPaste and when I console log on the event.clipboardData.files, I see that all the details within files is converted image even though I try to upload pdf or any other files.

However,

```
const text = (e['originalEvent'] || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
```

that does gives me proper file name. but  `event.clipboardData.files` holds image type, which messes up uploading file other than images.

```
*HTML*

<div onPaste={handlePaste}>

</div>

*JS*


const handlePaste = (e) => {
  console.log(e.clipboardData.files)
}
```

e above have this object within event.clipboardData.files

```
{
   lastModified: 1675788471866
   name: "image.png",
   size: 0,
   type: "image/png",
   webkitRelativePath: "",
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you